# Bootstrap 3 - Single column in a row, but not col-md-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

All of my input fields are width=100% so they fill 100% of whichever column they are in. Lets say I have a page that only needs 1 column but I don't want I don't want my fields going across the entire page (i.e. col-md-12). Instead, I would rather do something like this:

```
<div "class=container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   </row>
</div>
```

I thought you were always supposed to fill all 12 columns with bootstrap so it feels strange only doing one column of 4, but if I want the width of my form to be 4 then this is what I need to do. Should I even be using the bootstrap grid system on pages that don't need more then 1 column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add clearfix below the col-md-4.

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

You don't really have to fit all 12 columns...

Some of  their examples don't even fill up all 12 columns.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping

Comment: Was looking all over for an example where they didn't fill all 12! Thank you so much. What would adding the clearfix below col-md-4 help with? Spacing for a column under it?

Comment: And actually the example you sent me is an example of filling up more then 12 columns. Like 13. Can't believe they don't show a single 1 column on the left example besides col-md-12.

Comment: clearfix will just put any additional columns below the col-md-4 if you put additional columns in the same row, so the right side of col-md-4 will just be a blank space.